# Python string encode and decode

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

Encoding in JS means converting a string with special characters to escaped usable string. like : encodeURIComponent would convert spaces to %20 etc to be usable in URIs.

So encoding here means converting to a particular format.

In Python 2.7, I have a string : 奥多比. To convert it into UTF-8 format, however, I need to use decode() function.
Like: `"奥多比".decode("utf-8") ==  u'\u5965\u591a\u6bd4'`

I want to understand how the meaning of encode and decode is changing with language. To me essentially I should be doing `"奥多比".encode("utf-8")`

What am I missing here.

Comment: You convert **from** UTF-8 to a Unicode object.

Comment: Your console or terminal is set to UTF-8, so typing in `"奥多比"` sends *UTF-8 bytes* to the Python interactive interpreter process. Decoding then creates a Unicode object from the UTF-8 bytes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: SO when this is part of a script and I write : str = "奥多比." and then str.decode("utf-8") then that means that str is essentially the utf-8 already? However when I append it to the URL of an API call, it is sent as "奥多比." only and not in the encoded format.

Comment: So are you really asking how to send UTF-8 bytes in a URL?

Comment: URLs are not UTF-8 encoded. They are *percent encoded*, often using UTF-8 as a starting point. In Python 2, use `import urllib`, then `urllib.quote()` to create URL percent-encoded data. Start with UTF-8 bytes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you. What I essentially get from this is that the default encoding for python is UTF-8. the str is stored as UTF-8 encoded bytes and every print statement decodes this str and displays it/appends to another var. So for explicit encoded string, we decode() the UTF-8 string.

Comment: No, the default codec in Python 2 is ASCII.

Comment: Please do read the links I included. There are multiple moving parts here, and there is no simple one-comment answer as to what encodings are default where.

Comment: You haven't detailed how you tested your code, I am assuming you typed it into an interactive Python prompt in an IDE, or a console or terminal. At that point *the context sets the codec*. In a Linux or OS X terminal, the *locale* tells Python what codec to expect. In a file (script, module), Python defaults to ASCII unless you use a PEP 263 header to set something different. If you mix `unicode` and `str` types in your code, ASCII always applies, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be confusing [Unicode text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) (represented in Python 2 as the `unicode` type, indicated by the `u` prefix on the literal syntax), with one of the standard Unicode encodings, UTF-8.

You are not creating UTF-8, you created a Unicode text object, by *decoding* from a UTF-8 byte stream.

The *byte* string literal `"奥多比"' is a sequence of binary data, bytes. You either entered these in a text editor and saved the file as UTF-8 (and told Python to treat your source code as UTF-8 by starting the file with a [PEP 263 codec header](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)), or you typed it into the Python interactive prompt in a terminal that was configured to send UTF-8 data.

I strongly urge you to read more about the difference between bytes, codecs and Unicode text. The following links are highly recommended:

- Ned Batchelder's [*Pragmatic Unicode*](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)
- The Python [*Unicode HOWTO*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html)
- Joel Spolsky's [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/)

Comment: You mention that - `"奥多比"' is a byte literal. I think they are unicode characters. There is no purpose to decode them. Where as if we encode them then we get a byte representation. The byte representation can be transferred over network or file and the receiver can decode the byte to get the original `"奥多比" value. Have I got this concept right?

Comment: @variable: are you using Python 2? If not, then this is not something you need to worry about nearly as much. In any case, read the links I included, especially Ned Batchelder's. Try out the concepts in your interactive interpreter. Bytes are the lingua franca of data exchange, *everything* is bytes. Decoding to a text type (`unicode` in Python 2, `str` in Python 3) is turning bytes into a more useful object type, like using` datetime.strftime()` or `int()` or `json.load()`.

Comment: I'm using python 3 and have read that str in python 3+ is unicode

Answer (score 1):

In Python v2, it's type `str`, i.e. sequence of bytes. To convert it to a Unicode string, you need to decode this sequence of bytes using a *codec*. Simply said, it specifies how should bytes be converted to a sequence of Unicode code points. Look into [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html) for more in-depth article on this.